# PDF Creation for General Health report (sample image attached)

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GDBg.png)

I want to generate the PDF for Health Report on monthly basis for individual person , can any body help to create the PDF .

The sample PDF attached.

Answer (score 0):

you should use iText API for work on PDF creation.

Comment: i used the iText api and created the pdf and divide into two columns also  but can you see the attached image . like that i want to generate

Comment: any body help how to generate the PDF as in the attached formate

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class ImageExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document document = new Document();

    try {
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                new FileOutputStream("Image.pdf"));
        document.open();

        Image image1 = Image.getInstance("watermark.png");
        document.add(image1);


            String imageUrl = "IPaddress/sitename/images/" +
            "imagename.jpg";

            Image image2 = Image.getInstance(new URL(imageUrl));
        document.add(image2);

        document.close();
    } catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```